# Width of repeating backgrounds

Tags: css

What's best, a repeating background of 100px wide so that the actual file doesn't need to be redrawn 1000X times in width, or a 1px file that probably has smaller file size but the browser will need to redraw it a lot more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard image width to use for this sort of thing is 1 px. The smaller the image, the less data there is to transfer over the network, which means less time waiting for the page to load.

If you're going to be repeating some chunk of data anyway, why *not* make it as small as possible?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here but to answer your question: why *not* make it as small as possible. I thought maybe, if I make a repeating image 10px wide instead of 1px, maybe the drawing process in the browser would be faster because it would only have to repeat x / 10 times.

Comment: @tdskate: you're welcome to run your own performance tests. I think you'll find a negligible difference in paint speed between repeating a 1px image and a 10px image. Also, if you're _that_ concerned about the performance difference then you should be using a 10000px wide image so the browser doesn't ever have to repeat the image. Here's what you should really take away from the discussion: **if performance is an issue, use the tools available to you** (profilers and the like) **and then optimize the objectively identified bottlenecks.** You're only wasting your time with...

Answer (score 6):

A small file that the browser will have to repeat.  It takes almost no computer processing to repeat a 1kb file but repeating a 10-15kb file will be more taxing I'd think.  The smaller the better.